# How to add new column in pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have pandas groupby object

```
| A  | B | C |
|----|---|---|
| a1 | 3 | 4 |
| a2 | 6 | 2 |
```

And I want to add new column which will have average in row format

**Required Output**

```
| A  | B | C | Average |
|----|---|---|---------|
| a1 | 3 | 4 | 3.5     |
| a2 | 6 | 2 | 4       |
```

I tried

```
df.columns = df.columns.add_categories(['Average'])
df['Average'] = df.mean(axis = 1)
```

But this gives me

`AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'add_categories'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no catogoricals in columns names only use `mean`:

```
df['Average'] = df.mean(axis = 1)
```

Or if want convert columns names to `CategoricalIndex` then use:

```
df.columns = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.columns)
df.columns = df.columns.add_categories(['Average'])
df['Average'] = df.mean(axis = 1)
```